# Multiple Access Denied Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm creating an application that has two different authorization scenarios: admin and site.

If you try to access a `/admin` route without the policy succeeding the user should be redirected to an access denied page.  At this point there's no action the user can take.  They can't access the resource and there's nothing for them to do.

If you try to access a `/site/joes-super-awesome-site` route without the policy suceeding the user should be redirected to a *different* access denied.  At this point the user should be able to request access.  There is an action they can take.

What's the best way to achieve this?  I know I can override the default `OnRedirectToAccessDenied` action but that will require some ugly string parsing (untested example below).

```
.AddCookie(options => {
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context => {
        // parsing this kinda sucks.
        var pathParts = context.Request.Path.Value.Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (pathParts?[0] == "site") {
            context.Response.Redirect($"/{pathParts[0]}/request-access");
        } else {
            context.Response.Redirect("/account/access-denied");
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing some searching, I found the following information:

- Someone with the same question on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1530)
- Tracking of authorization-related improvements in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1359#issuecomment-388801434)

---

Unfortunately these improvements didn't make it to ASP.NET Core 2.1.

It seems that at this point, another option (apart from your suggestion of parsing the request URL) is to imperatively invoke the authorization service in your MVC actions.

It could go from:

```cs
// Highly imaginary current implementation
public class ImaginaryController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("site/{siteName}")]
    [Authorize("SitePolicy")]
    public IActionResult Site(string siteName)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet("admin")]
    [Authorize("AdminPolicy")]
    public IActionResult Admin()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

to:

```cs
public class ImaginaryController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorization;

    public ImaginaryController(IAuthorizationService authorization)
    {
        _authorization = authorization;
    }

    [HttpGet("site/{siteName}")]
    public Task<IActionResult> Site(string siteName)
    {
        var sitePolicyAuthorizationResult = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(User, "SitePolicy");
        if (!sitePolicyAuthorizationResult.Success)
        {
            return Redirect($"/site/{siteName}/request-access");
        }

        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet("admin")]
    public Task<IActionResult> Admin()
    {
        var adminPolicyAuthorizationResult = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(User, "AdminPolicy");
        if (!adminPolicyAuthorizationResult.Success)
        {
            return Redirect("/account/access-denied");
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm not big on the idea of having to "opt-in" to securing each method, but it's definitely an interesting idea!